# Spring data Mongo DB: weird behaviour of findByName

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Mongo DB collection called studentGroup. These have unique indexed "name" attribute. I have implemented a regular MongoRepository and declared *Optional findByName(String name)* method in it. 
Problem is, as ridiculous as it sounds, it does not find any results although it should. It is clear that the documents are saved in the database. I also have an autocomplete method that is supposed to return list of objects to the service layer (findByNameStartingWithIgnoreCase), which is the actual needed method. 
Funny thing is that the same thing works perfectly with other collections in the same database. Implementation is identical, and I have tripple-checked if I have any hidden copy-paste bugs, but no, everything is implemented perfectly.

What is even more weird, when I call findAll over repository, I obtain a list of these documents. When I debug it in eclipse and inspect the returned list, the name of the group is literally represented like this:

```
id= "5caadas..."
name= "
students= ArrayList<E>
...
```

When I click on name attribute (still in inspect mode), it shows *name="Group 1"*, but as soon as I lift my finger of the touchpad (meaning as soon as my "click" is completed), name in the inspection goes back to *name= "*. As if some weird lazy loading is happening... But I did not declare such thing anywhere in my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: weird yes ! why not delete errorsome collection and start with new first record... just debugging techs

Comment: Ok found it. The attribute values are for some reason in unicode within the database. But one cannot see that the database entries are encoded wrongly as both debugger in eclipse and tools such as Robo 3T implicitly decode the values into plain text. Terminal shows actual (incorrect) data.